# Why does updating my nested Reagent component not update it?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, shadow-cljs

I have a triply nested component (in different files) in Reagent + ShadowCLJS. When editing and saving this file, the changes don't show immediately until editing and saving the parent component.

For example, NAV is nested in DASHBOARD which itself is nested in APP. Editing and saving DASHBOARD result in changes also in the browser, but editing and saving NAV does not, until DASHBOARD itself is modified, then NAV will show changes in the browser.

Example code:

```clj
(ns app.core
  (:require [app.views.dashboard :as dash]))
(defn app[]
  [dashboard])
```

```clj
(ns app.views.dashboard
  (:require [app.components.nav :as nav]))
(defn dashboard[]
  [:div 
    [:div "Dashboard"]
    [nav/nav]])
```

```clj
(ns app.components.nav)
(defn nav[]
  [:div "Navigation"])
```

Build configuration:

```clj
;;shadow-cljs.edn
...
{:app {:target :browser
       :modules {:main {:entries [app.core]}}}
...
```

I tried un-nesting the namespaces so that the components live next to each other in the directory, but still triply nested. This also does not work.

Comment: Should't that be `dash/dashboard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote about [hot-reload in CLJS](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2019/08/25/hot-reload-in-clojurescript.html), maybe you can find an answer there.

Normally I'd expect your setup to just work, but I suspect that reagent/react decides to skip rendering at some point. They memoize some components and since CORE doesn't change, when touching NAV it may decide that nothing needs to be done.

You can force a full reload by setting `:devtool {:reload-strategy :full}` in your build config, which should address this problem. It may however become somewhat slow in larger builds.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, just wanted to add that my build config now looks like this for those (like me) looking for an answer. 
`:builds {: app {:target :browser :devtools {:reload-strategy :full} :modules {:main {:entries [app.core]}}}}`

Answer (score 1):

After 5 hours of meddling around, it turns out if C is nested in B which is nested in A (A (B (C))), not only do you have to import C inside B, but you also have to import it inside A. So my solution was to also `:require`  `app.components.nav` inside `app.core`.

I'm not very sure why this behaves like this, so if anyone else would like to respond with an explanation, that would be welcome!